# Angular - Custom Elements not working on Firefox & Microsoft Edge & Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-component, custom-element

I tried this [Angular Elements Demo](https://github.com/vogloblinsky/angular-elements-demo)

I downloaded, installed, and built that demo on local.

Then, used the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Elements Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

  <hello-world name="Anna"></hello-world>

  <script src="dist/main.js"></script>
  <script>
      const helloCp = document.querySelector('hello-world');
      helloCp.addEventListener('hi', (data) => {
          console.log(data.detail);
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        helloCp.setAttribute('name', 'Marc');
      }, 1000);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I tried on `Mozilla Firefox` but getting the following error:

```
"ReferenceError: customElements is not defined"
```

In the other hand, I tried on `Google Chrome` and !!! it works properly !!!

Maybe I need to include some Javascript file like a `polyfill`?
I tried some of them recommended on internet with no success.

It also didn't work on `Microsoft Edge` and `Internet Explorer`.

Is there anyway to get the code running on Firefox without tweaking its default configuration?

I mean, on Firefox: `about:config`

```
dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled: true
dom.webcomponents.shadowdom.enabled: true
```

I tried adding the following Javascript file:
https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/v1/webcomponents-lite.js

as recommended here:
https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills

but there was no success

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I got my Custom Elements project to work in other browsers by removing `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`

Comment: This has been the only answer I have found in days that allowed me to get it working in Edge! But still not IE.

Answer (score 1):

> Custom elements are a Web Platform feature currently supported by
>   Chrome, Opera, and Safari, and available in other browsers through
>   polyfills (see Browser Support).

So, you should add **polyfills** to work with Firefox, <s>Edge...</s>

[Browser support for custom elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements#browser-support-for-custom-elements)

> Note: Custom elements are supported by default in Chrome and Opera.
>   Firefox  is very close; they are currently available if you set the
>   preferences dom.webcomponents.enabled and
>   **dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled** to **true**. Firefox's
>   implementation is planned to be enabled by **default in version 60/61**.
>   Safari so far supports only autonomous custom elements, and Edge is
>   working on an implementation as well.

[Official Docs.](https://angular.io/guide/elements)

Comment: is it possible to use a `polyfill` for this from some `CDN`?, or do I have to generate a `polyfill` specifically for my project?

Comment: @davidesp, updated answer, check `Browser support for custom elements` reference

Comment: is there anyway to get the code running on Firefox without tweaking its default configuration? I tried adding the following Javascript file: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/v1/webcomponents-lite.js
as recommended here: https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills but there was no success

Answer (score -1):

Angular custom elements does not support IE. Here is a workaround to Customize Angular 4+ App Bootstrap and have it support with IE.

https://hongbinhb.blogspot.com/2019/02/how-to-deploy-two-or-more-angular-6.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.