# Angular Elements Polyfills to use in IE11 and Edge problems

Tags: angular, angular-elements

Following on from my [last post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568996/angular-elements-uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-construct-htmlelement), where I have an Angular elements project, which I can get working in Chrome if compile with TS target of `es2015`, I have now gone back to compile with `es5` (in preparation to try and get working in Edge and IE11).

After the build to `es5`, I combine the following output files:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');

(async function build() {  
  const files = [
    './dist/angular-webcomponents-demo/runtime.js',
    './dist/angular-webcomponents-demo/polyfills.js',
    './dist/angular-webcomponents-demo/scripts.js',
    './dist/angular-webcomponents-demo/main.js',
  ]

  await fs.ensureDir('elements')
  await concat(files, 'elements/analytics-counter.js');    
  console.info('Angular Elements created successfully!')

})()
```

One question I have is when I build the project, I get two polyfill files, `es2015-polyfills.js` and `polyfills.js`.

And I have just included the `polyfills.js` in the concat script above, so wondering what the `es2015-polyfills.js` is for.

Carrying on, I then include the built component in a very simple test application, and now include the two scripts from the `@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs` package

So my test host html now looks like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  
  <!-- Polyfill for Chrome since we built element using es5 -->
  <script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>

  <!-- Polyfill for Edge and IE -->
  <script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom element script  -->
  <script src="analytics-counter-es5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Custom element....  -->
  <analytics-counter></analytics-counter>  
</body>
</html>
```

I now test using `http-server -p 8209`, and first this works in Chrome, so I assume this is the `custom-elements-es5-adapter.js` working for the es5 built component.

Next Edge I get the error:

`ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'createShadowRoot'`

Also, in the vscode terminal where I am running http-server, I see the following output with a lot of 404s (scroll to the right):

```
        Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:19 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;
    x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:19 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/webcomponents-sd-ce-pf.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:19 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /favicon.ico" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:19 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/webcomponents-sd-ce-pf.js.map" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:19 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/util/makeiterator]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:util/global]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/util/setprototypeof]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:util/defineproperty]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/generator_engine]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/util/arrayfromiterator]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/util/makeiterator]" Error (404): "Not found"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:util/global]" Error (404): "Not found"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/util/setprototypeof]" Error (404): "Not found"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:util/defineproperty]" Error (404): "Not found"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/util/arrayfromiterable]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/symbol]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/generator_engine]" Error (404): "Not
    found"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/util/arrayfromiterator]" Error (404): "Not found"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/util/arrayfromiterable]" Error (404): "Not found"
    [Wed Aug 21 2019 15:01:20 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)] "GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:es6/symbol]" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Finally in IE, I see the following:

[image]

Also interestingly for IE there are no errors in the vscode terminal as I saw for Edge.

So, it appears the `webcomponents-loader.js` is not working for Edge and IE.

Note I have included these polyfills in the test host app, and NOT the project where I build the component. DO these belong in the host app, or the actual component itself, which seem to be what is happening [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QU0mpyF7bQ) (see around 21.10)..

[image]

Why does the polyfill not seem to be working for Edge and IE?

### Update 1

I could get to work in Edge by following the suggestions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313140/angular-custom-elements-not-working-on-firefox-microsoft-edge-internet-exp), ie I removed the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` and it now works in Edge (and Firefox). My remaining problem is IE where I get the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames: argument is not an Object` error.

This is coming from the following:

[image]

### Update 2

Both Edge and Firefox seem to work **without** the `webcomponents-loader.js` included, however without this, IE gets a different error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'from'`

Adding it back, Firefox and Edge both still work, though a request via edge does show errors in the http-server console:

`"GET /node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/%20[synthetic:util/global]" Error (404): "Not found"` - even so, the element still renders.

So, IE is still not working.

Comment: were able to find solution to this problem ?

Comment: @sam_dev - unfortunately no. after spending quite some time on it, I had to give up on this, and haven't tried again since.