# Angular 8 Custom element on IE11/Edge gives "createdCallback" error

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-elements

I have created an Angular Element application which is a Chat widget. Everything works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, but I have a problem with launching my widget on IE and Edge.
Once I run it locally, everything works fine even on IE and Edge, but once I tried to run it on production, on IE console I can see this error:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/namQ5.png]

I have totally no idea what's going on, but my chat is not even appear on site, because all I can see is this error in IE console.
Have you ever faced this kind of problem? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: may this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313140/angular-custom-elements-not-working-on-firefox-microsoft-edge-internet-exp) will be helpful for you.

Comment: Hey, thank you for link but it is not associated with my problem. During the investigation, I have found out, that those methods, are gathered from document-register-element.js script. Should I add some other polyfills to my project?

Comment: I found that this kind of error occurs when using a mat-sort or ngrx router. Are you using some kind of dependency or library? If yes, you can remove it and take a test again. I also suggest you create an issue on GitHub. Try to know the opinion of other users may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I found out, that on production, there is a script **document-register-element.js** loaded before my widget scripts load. If I place it above declaration of **document-register-element.js**, it is loading properly on IE and EDGE.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding